# A short way to determine the divergence of the integral: $\int\limits_0^1 \left| \frac{1}{x}\cos\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) \right| dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals, lebesgue-integral, bounded-variation

The integral
 $$\int_0^1 \left| \frac{1}{x}\cos\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) \right| dx$$I can use the subsets in the form 
$$\left[ \frac{1}{(2k+7/3)\pi} , \frac{1}{(2k+5/3)\pi}\right]$$ where the cosine function is bigger than 1/2 in these subsets we will get the summation $$\sum_{0}^{\infty} \ln \left( 1+ \frac{2}{6k+5}\right) $$ I am trying to show that $f(x)=x^2\sin(1/x^2)$ on the interval $[0,1]$ is not of bounded variation by showing that $f’$ is not integrable. ( Royden book 4th edition page 114)

Comment: Are you looking for a sartorial solution?

Comment: @copper.hat sartorial?

Comment: The title was looking for a shirt way :-).

Comment: For $|x|$ sufficiently small you have $\log(1+x) \ge {1 \over 2} x$. That will give divergence. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: @PeterForeman: It is not equivalent, but is a lower bound.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm, how about instead of bounding the cosine in the integral and integrating the $\frac{1}{x}$, you in fact bound both of them.

$$\int_{((2k+7/3) \pi)^{-1}}^{((2k+5/3)\pi)^{-1}} \left|\frac{1}{x}\cos(\frac{1}{x})\right| dx \geq \left(\frac{1}{(2k+5/3)\pi}-\frac{1}{(2k+7/3) \pi}\right)(2k+\frac{5}{3})\pi* \cos(\frac{7\pi}{3} ) = \frac{2\pi C(2k+\frac{5}{3})\pi}{3(2k+5/3)\pi*(2k+7/3)\pi} = \frac{C'}{(2k+7/3)} $$

Then you can sum these to show divergence.

Comment: Why that’s true?

Comment: It comes from taking the lower bound of the cosine and the inverse $x$ on the interval in question and multiplying by the length of the interval

Comment: What copper hat said about bounding the logarithm is pretty much the same thing

Comment: The lower bound for cosine is zero, -1 ?

Comment: Yes but on this interval it is $\cos(\frac{7\pi}{3})$

Comment: Is there any way without dividing the interval [0,1] ?

Comment: It would be more effort than it is worth haha